# How can I use Roboto font via XML and styles tag only in android

Tags: android

I am confused in using Roboto font in my project. Basically I don't know the proper way to use this font. I have multiple .tff files and I want to apply Roboto font to my whole project. minsdk is 15.

**EDIT**
I just want to include the fonts via XML files.

Comment: @Kling Klang Why duplicate? I just dont want to apply the styling to TextView only. I am talking about whole application and also I dont want to do this via java code.

Comment: Please read the duplicate, see the various answers and understand that once you define a style all the views (with the proper attributes set) will inherit the properties defined in that style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**STEP 1/**

Start by creating a folder named `assests` then inside that folder create another one named `folder` and import your `*.ttf` files to that folder

**STEP 2/**

Now import this before start writing the code given below:

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
```

Now implement the following code to your class:

```
// Font path
String fontPath = "fonts/Face Your Fears.ttf";

// text view label
TextView txtGhost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ghost);

// Loading Font Face
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

// Applying font
txtGhost.setTypeface(tf);
```

I suggest you follow this tutorial [right here](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-using-external-fonts/) it will guide step-by-step through using external fonts in Android Studio

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18510102)

Comment: you are absolutely right , the answer is updated now, thanks for the heads-up

Comment: I want to do it via styling and XML only. Is there any way that I can use custom fonts single time and it applies to whole application?